# Drop down menu not working in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, controller

I have a webpage which has a navigation bar like

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
      <c:out value="${pageContext.request.remoteUser}"/>
      <span class="caret"></span>
     </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>
       <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Logout</a> 
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

Now when i click on the drop-down menu instead of showing me the option to Logout nothing happens and it just appends a "#" to the url . For example is the usr is `http://localhost:8080/index` it becomes `http://localhost:8080/index#` . How can i avoid this

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
     class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
     class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="/static/images/Snapdeal.png"></a>
  </div>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling 
  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" /> -->
  <form id="logout-form" class="form-inline" action="/logout" style="display: none">
   <input type="submit" value="Logout" class="btn btn-link" />
   
  </form>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <h3 class="navbar-text"><b>Crux Admin</b></h3>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <c:choose>
     <c:when test="${param.currentPage eq 'dashboard'}">
      <c:set var="classValue" value="active" />
     </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
      <c:set var="classValue" value="" />
     </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    <li class="${classValue}"><a href="/index">Dashboard</a></li>
   </ul>
   
   
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
      <c:out value="${pageContext.request.remoteUser}"/>
      <span class="caret"></span>
     </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>
       <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Logout</a> 
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
 </div>
 <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

This is the entire page

Comment: Do you have an element of id `#logout-form` on your page? You haven't supplied enough code to reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: @Serlite i have put the whole page now

Comment: Ignore this, comment, it won't let me delete it

Comment: That is not the entire page. The entire page would start at <html>, and would end at </html>. Did you include the necessary JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in  part of ur page, it will work

```
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```